# In what circumstances will a process be in state X (dead)?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, process, source-code

According to [`fs/proc/array.c:130`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/fs/proc/array.c#L130), the following array defines various process states:

```
/*
 * The task state array is a strange "bitmap" of
 * reasons to sleep. Thus "running" is zero, and
 * you can test for combinations of others with
 * simple bit tests.
 */
static const char * const task_state_array[] = {

    /* states in TASK_REPORT: */
    "R (running)",      /* 0x00 */
    "S (sleeping)",     /* 0x01 */
    "D (disk sleep)",   /* 0x02 */
    "T (stopped)",      /* 0x04 */
    "t (tracing stop)", /* 0x08 */
    "X (dead)",         /* 0x10 */
    "Z (zombie)",       /* 0x20 */
    "P (parked)",       /* 0x40 */

    /* states beyond TASK_REPORT: */
    "I (idle)",         /* 0x80 */
};
```

According to [`proc(5)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), the `X` state was added in kernel 2.6.0:

> X  Dead (from Linux 2.6.0 onward)
>
> x  Dead (Linux 2.6.33 to 3.13 only)

And according to [`ps(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html), the `X` shouldn't be seen:

> X    dead (should never be seen)

Looking at the rest of the source code, it seems like it *is* used internally by the kernel. In the source file [`kernel/sched.core.c:4176`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L4176), a comment briefly describes it:

```
/*
 * A task struct has one reference for the use as "current".
 * If a task dies, then it sets TASK_DEAD in tsk->state and calls
 * schedule one last time. The schedule call will never return, and
 * the scheduled task must drop that reference.
 *
 * We must observe prev->state before clearing prev->on_cpu (in
 * finish_task), otherwise a concurrent wakeup can get prev
 * running on another CPU and we could rave with its RUNNING -> DEAD
 * transition, resulting in a double drop.
 */
```

It also appears to be *required* in some cases. In [`kernel/fork.c:424`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/kernel/fork.c#L424):

```
static void release_task_stack(struct task_struct *tsk)
{
    if (WARN_ON(tsk->state != TASK_DEAD))
        return;  /* Better to leak the stack than to free prematurely */

    account_kernel_stack(tsk, -1);
    free_thread_stack(tsk);
    tsk->stack = NULL;
#ifdef CONFIG_VMAP_STACK
    tsk->stack_vm_area = NULL;
#endif
}
```

It looks to me like `TASK_DEAD` is set for a process when it terminates but before the kernel finally destroys `task_struct`, so it should never appear as a process state unless there is a kernel bug that fails to clean up the process. There's also [these lecture notes](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Ejunfeng/13fa-w4118/lectures/l07-proc-xv6.pdf) which reinforces this idea:

> TASK_DEAD – the process is being cleaned up and the task is being deleted

So to my real question:

**In what circumstances will a process be reported by `ps` as being in state X?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task state represented by “X” isn’t `TASK_DEAD`, it’s [the `EXIT_DEAD` exit state](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/include/linux/sched.h#L88). `TASK_DEAD` itself isn’t [a reportable state](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/include/linux/sched.h#L111), and while `EXIT_DEAD` is, [it isn’t supposed to be visible in practice](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=ad86622b478eaafdc25b74237df82b10fce6326d).

`EXIT_DEAD`’s role is similar to what you describe for `TASK_DEAD`: a task’s exit state is set to `EXIT_DEAD` shortly before its `task_struct` is deleted by `release_task`; see for example [`de_thread`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/fs/exec.c#L1140), [`release_task` itself](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/kernel/exit.c#L217), and [`exit_notify`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.12.9/source/kernel/exit.c#L688).

I haven’t checked the locking in detail, and [changing process state can be seen by readers](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/RCU/listRCU.html#example-1-read-mostly-list-deferred-destruction); however it seems unlikely that a process would ever be seen in `EXIT_DEAD` state by another process.

Whether it can be seen or not, a process is in state “X” once it’s fully exited and its `task_struct` is about to be deleted.